# How to union 3 tables and join it with another one in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have three tables, each with different columns and one superclass table. I have a unique id for each entity that's in the superclass table and its own table.

I want to union the three tables and then join the result with the superclass table based on the id.

How do I go about this? I only have the unique id and no other information.

**Edit:**
I tried what you suggested but got this exception:

```
08-01 18:49:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(10737): Caused by:      
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not 
have   the same number of result columns: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM 
pois UNION SELECT * FROM routes UNION SELECT * FROM events) t INNER JOIN features ON (pid 
= t.features_pid)) WHERE pid = "poi2114"
```

Comment: you have done select * from . But you should select the fields which are common in the tables you are doing union.

Comment: ah ok I get it, but for the result I need all the columns of that table

Comment: You can only select fields common in all the tables for union. You can add dummy fields in other tables in select query like SELECT null as name, 2 as number etc to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Nested queries can serve as tables in the FROM clause.

```
select * from (
    select ID from TableA
    union
    select ID from TableB) ab inner join TableX x on ab.ID = x.FooID
```

The field names in the constructed table `ab` follow the names in the first select that constitutes `ab`. So if the field in TableB is called something else, it will still be under the ID column. That's how UNION queries work.

Also, be mindful of the UNION ALL/UNION DISTINCT distinction.